# Django AJAX POST login CSRF error in IE, EDGE, etc

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, authentication, csrf

I'm using Django 1.10.

I want to log in via Jquery AJAX, but CSRF is set on.

In order to pass the CSRF check, I have the following code (in a standalone js file).

```js
   /*  CSRF-config Start */
$.ajaxSetup({ 
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         function getCookie(name) {
             var cookieValue = null;
             if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                 var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                     var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                     if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                         cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     } 
});
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT' || settings.type == 'DELETE') {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
    /*  CSRF-config End */
```

Chrome works perfectly here, logged in with no issues.

However, when I switch to IE, Edge, etc. The following error occurred:

"""

Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login/

[25/Aug/2016 08:58:42] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2857

"""

The code I have seems not working at all. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here! I figured out a solution.

The following code should **ONLY** be written in **template html page**.

DO NOT leave it to a standalone JS file.

Delete other related CSRF AJAXSetup code in case of conflicts.

```
<!-- Bla bla bla your login form, input, etc. -->
<script>
  $.ajaxSetup({
      data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Django docs:

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. 
>   [Read more...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/)

You can use your existing static JS with one of two solutions:

1. Make sure to include `{% csrf_token %}` in the template.  Normally it goes in a form, but if you aren't using forms just put it somewhere in the body.
2. Add the [`@ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator to your view function.

I've only had this issue with IE in the past